# How to sieve a raster with 1 and NaN values?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, remote-sensing

As a next step to my previous question "[How to calculate where raster a is not equal to raster b?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251374/gdal-calc-how-to-calculate-where-raster-a-is-not-equal-to-raster-b)", I now want to sieve (using QGIS -> Raster -> Analysis -> Sieve, or `gdal_sieve` in the shell) a raster which consists of the values `1` and `NaN`.
The problem is: no matter what parameters I tell `gdal_sieve` to use, it still returns the original raster, nothing happens.

[image: Pixels I want so sieve out]

Above you can see the raster (black pixels) that I want to sieve. Actually, this screenshot was taken immediately after the sieve algorithm ran through. You will find that nothing was sieved.

I guess this is because gdal_sieve cannot handle `NaN`, so the nearest possible value always is `1` again, if it skips the `NaN`s.

Because I want to use [Zonal Statistics](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html) with this raster and some polygons afterwards, it is necessary that this raster consists just of `1` and `NaN`, because I am interested in the total count of pixels with value `1` in a polygon. If I would use a raster with, say `0` and `1`, it would always accumulate these two in my *count* column.

Does anyone have an idea how to workaround this?

Comment: Can you post your gdal_sieve command, please. This works for me: `gdal_sieve -st 100 -8 -nomask not_sieved.sdat -of "GTIFF" sieved.tif`. Everything >100 connected pixel will be excluded with a treshold of 8.

Comment: This seems to work for me as well, thank you! I have only tried it via the QGIS GUI yet, but because the `gdal_sieve` command is shown below there, I didn't think that typing it in a bash script would function differently. The `-nomask` flag seems to make the difference, trying the same parameters via the GUI still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from Stefans comment works for me:

```
gdal_sieve.py -st 8 -8 -nomask S2_2015_AOI_Bebaut.tif -of "GTIFF" sieved.tif
```

The only difference I can see between the GUI version in QGIS and this bash command is the `-nomask` flag, which cannot be set in QGIS. This seems to do the trick. The [official GDAL doc](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html) describes its function as follows:

> Do not use the default validity mask for the input band (such as nodata, or alpha masks).

I cannot fully understand what this means, but as long as it works, I'm fine with it.

Comment: I had the same problem, but as of QGIS 3, there is a tick box in the GUI for 'Do not use the default validity mask for the input band'.